# Comparing a value and a reference

Tags: rust

Consider the following Rust function, which is meant to indicate whether the given 3-byte string is equal to `b"foo"`.

```
fn is_foo(value: [u8; 3]) -> bool {
    value == b"foo"
}
```

This doesn't work:

> error[E0277]: can't compare `[u8; 3]` with `&[u8; 3]`

The compiler is complaining that it can't compare a value of some type to a reference of the same type.

I found two ways of getting the equality check to work:

- Turning the value into a ref first: `&value == b"foo"`
- Turning the ref into a value first: `value == *b"foo"`

Coming from C++ (where a value and a reference are pretty much the same thing), both approaches look a bit strange to me. What is the most idiomatic way of comparing a value and a reference?

Comment: AFAIK a rust reference is a [bit like a C++ pointer, and a bit like a C++ reference](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-ref-in-rust-more-similar-to-c-pointer-rather-than-c-referene/14167). So that may not be a great comparison.

Comment: I'd go with `&value == b"foo"`

Comment: I would argue for fn is_foo(value : &[u8; 3]) as an improved function definition. The equality will then work as-is, plus is_foo does not need ownership in any case. You are only pushing a couple of bytes onto the stack, but it would certainly be preferable in a situation where value is a large number of bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rust `T` and `&T` (and also `&mut T`) are **different** types. Though different types *can* be compared it is not standard. Equality comparison (the `==` operator) is done by [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait. It looks like this:

```rust
pub trait PartialEq<Rhs = Self> where
    Rhs: ?Sized,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;

    fn ne(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool { ... }
}
```

And although it is generic over `Rhs` (meaning that one type can potentially be compared with many other types), it defaults to `Self`.

So coming back to your example you could just write `value.eq(b"foo")` (that would compare values of references), but though it is not wrong, probably more often is `&value == b"foo"`. Dereferencing is fine too, but I seldom see it.

You also don't have to be worry, that equality between types and their references will differ, because standard library has following blanket implementation (and others for mutable references):

```rust
impl<A, B> PartialEq<&B> for &A where
    A: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
    B: ?Sized, 
{ ... }
```

That automatically implements equality for references in a proper way.